# Which has better .NET implementation, Mercurial or git?

Tags: .net, git, mercurial

I need to access some DVCS from my .NET code and because I'm familiar with Mercurial and Git, which one of that two has better .NET client library? And I don't mean just a wrapper, I mean a full .NET implementation not requiring any command line calls in the background.

Note: If the answer was Bazaar or some other DVCS that I'm not familiar with, it's OK, the actual DVCS is not that important.

**Edit:** I'm looking for answers from people that have actually tried some .NET clients and can judge their quality.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for Git, but Mercurial has no API in any language - everything is intended to be done via the command line.

Comment: Thanks, if that's true then Mercurial is ruled out.

Comment: According to the Mercurial wiki - http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi - The *published, documented, and stable API* is the command line

Answer (score 3):

NGit is not a wrapper. https://github.com/slluis/ngit

It is based on JGit and makes a lightweight access library for .NET world.

It drives e.g. monodevelop source control integration and can do everything you can do with the commandline tools, except "Look ma, no external binaries"

Answer (score 1):

Both have native .NET support:

- Git - [Git#](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp)
- Mercurial - [Mercurial.NET](http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/)

The choice is yours.

Comment: One is a wrapper and the other one has been put on hold. I'm looking for kind of quality comparison between the implementations - how good and usable in real projects they really are.

Comment: @Borek: That would make this a subjective question then.  You don't want to go down that path otherwise it will probably end up being closed.

Comment: @Borek, I agree with @Jeff. From the moment you ask which one of the two is better your question becomes eligible for closing.

Comment: @Jeff Quality can be measured. The thing is that I can find a list of .NET implementations quite easily on Google, what I can't find is their assessment which is why I asked here.

Comment: @Darin BTW see the "related" column - I think this very question is much less subjective than many of them :)

Comment: NGit is not a wrapper :) It drives e.g. monodevelop source control integration and can do everything you can do with the commandline tools, except "Look ma, no external binaries

Answer (score 1):

There are no "native" implementation of Mercurial (and there will likely never be). Your best bet would be the hglib project, which uses the cmdserver mode of Mercurial (part of a [GSoC project](http://idankgsochg.blogspot.com/2011/06/first-poc.html)).

Comment: A full port of the Mercurial software package is a huge undertaking, it is unlikely anyone will do a full port. Not only would you have to reimplement/port all the code already present, but you would need a full understanding of everything, and you would also need to keep up with bugfixes and additions. At the moment I don't think there are any .NET ports of any of the Mercurial code.

Comment: It seems that for Git, such port exists so it will probably be a winner for me.

Comment: Lasse: a native port was done to Java: http://hg4j.com/ so while it is a big job, it is by no means impossible.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up what was gathered in the answers: it looks that Mercurial doesn't have and probably won't have a .NET port any time soon while for Git, at least these two ports seem usable:

- [NGit](https://github.com/slluis/ngit) (automated port of JGit)
- [GitSharp](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp)